# Changing hosts for MySQL Cluster Users

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a MariaDB Cluster in place and sometimes i need to change my hosts for some users, but, these changes are not propagated all over the Cluster.

Let's say `UPDATE mysql.user SET host = '10.99.0.%' WHERE host = '%' AND user != 'root';`

Is it a normal situation? I need to proceed each change in each Cluster member.

Am i doing it wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about NDB Cluster?  Or Galera Cluster?  Please tag accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System tables are MyISAM, and Galera does not replicate updates to MyISAM tables by default, it's a [known limitation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-galera-cluster-known-limitations/):

> Currently replication works only with the InnoDB storage engine. Any
>   writes to tables of other types, including system (mysql.*) tables are
>   not replicated (this limitation excludes DDL statements such as CREATE
>   USER, which implicitly modify the mysql.* tables — those are
>   replicated). There is however experimental support for MyISAM - see
>   the `wsrep_replicate_myisam` system variable)

If you decide to try `wsrep_replicate_myisam`, be careful about it, "experimental" means unstable and not recommended for production.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. So i have no other choice than do it manually.